# Dynamic tab in jquery fails to be selected after creation

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I am creating a dynamic tab via an "tab-add" button.

The "tab-add" button is appended to the end of the tab and then the tab is initialised, e.g.

```
$('#tabs').sortable({
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        $tabs = $( '#tabtab' ).tabs({
            create: function(event, ui) {
                $('#tabs').append( '<li id="tab-add" class="noSort"></li>' );
            },
            add: function( event, ui ) { ...
```

[image]

When the "tab-add" button ( which is in fact an li ) is clicked a new tab is created using the .tabs( 'add', href, input ) notation. I then inject an input field into this generated tab li. This removes the default generated link within the newly created li.

[image]

```
<li id="tab-1">
    <input type="text" id="tab-input"></input>
</li>
```

[image]

This works fine when the input loses focus the information gathered in the input is posted to a database and the correct li syntax is returned into id "tab-1".

```
<li id="tab-1">
    <a href="#tabs-1">The Name of My New Tab</a>
</li>
```

Now, this is where I get stuck.

The correct tab is selected (seen above) and the panel is showing, however when I click on another already created tab and then click back on my just generated tab the tab will not select (see below). When I try to click the "The Name Of My New Tab" tab it doesn't select (highlight).

[image]

This has something to do with the fact that the content of "tab-1" was dynamically generated and the tab has not regenerated itself. Since, if I go ahead and add another new tab the tab starts to work fine. I don't want to do a page refresh I just want that tab to work immediately after its been generated. I've tried selecting, loading and enabling the tab with no effect.

Is there a slick way to regenerate the tabs after this dynamic approach?

I hope this read has not been too dull! Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I get it now.  The problem is that when you add a new tab, the jquery.ui code is attaching a bunch of handlers to that  tag that you are then replacing.  Instead of replacing this  tag, just hide it.  Then when the input loses focus, change the text inside that  which was created by jquery.ui and show it again.  This way you keep all the handlers attached by jquery.ui.

Comment: Afraid I don't have a live server to provide the sort of example you would need just yet.

Comment: This was meant to be a comment, not an answer, nobody yell at me!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A Tab is created and the handlers are added to the tag as you say. However, the li itself is not removed and those handlers stay intact. The contents of the li is all that changes. No handlers are applied to the contents as far as I can see in firebug.

Comment: The "The Name Of My New Tab" wont allow you to click it. The over state works but I can't click it to change its state.

Comment: From what I saw inspecting a tab with chrome, there were 3 handlers on the <a> within the li after a tab was added.

Comment: I can't see these handlers on <a> all I get is <a href="#tabs-1"></a> after I add a tab while stepping through with firebug. But they may be there and that could well be the issue. Is there another way to initialise the tab after its created so it can be manipulated (selected or made active)?

Comment: OK, i've done as suggested and hidden the anchor and moved the input value into the anchor tag and hey presto! It works. So dynamically mucking about with the <a> after its been created is not a good idea. Thanks for your time.